# Meteor developer - Does anyone have a fix for Meteor not running on iOS 10 iPhone 6 Plus?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova

I have upgrade my iPhone 6 Plus to iOS 10, XCode to 8.0 and also run the following meteor command:

meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp@https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp.git#8bf95eed3f313299fc2de33658866278eea2cdc5

I then run:

meteor run ios-device --mobile-server localhost:3000

the app deployed to my iPhone 6 Plus (iOS 10), but when I run the app, it will display the meteor logo/splash screen and shutdown immediately.

When I Compile in XCode 8.0 with SWIFT 3 and Target for iPhone 6 Plus with iOS 1.0

I got the following error messages:

```
Deprecations Group
/Users/brianthanhnguyen/dev/MyApp/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/MyApp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine/CDVWKWebViewEngine.m:277:91: 'stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use -stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters: instead, which always uses the recommended UTF-8 encoding, and which encodes for a specific URL component or subcomponent since each URL component or subcomponent has different rules for what characters are valid.
/Users/brianthanhnguyen/dev/MyApp/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/MyApp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/CDVStatusBar.m:272:44: 'setStatusBarStyle:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:440:50: Property 'statusBarStyle' is declared deprecated here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:440:50: 'setStatusBarStyle:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
/Users/brianthanhnguyen/dev/MyApp/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/MyApp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/CDVStatusBar.m:369:14: 'setStatusBarHidden:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use -[UIViewController prefersStatusBarHidden]
/Users/brianthanhnguyen/dev/MyApp/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/MyApp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/CDVStatusBar.m:401:14: 'setStatusBarHidden:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use -[UIViewController prefersStatusBarHidden]
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:444:63: Property 'statusBarHidden' is declared deprecated here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:444:63: 'setStatusBarHidden:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
/Users/brianthanhnguyen/dev/MyApp/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/MyApp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/CDVStatusBar.m:460:48: 'applicationFrame' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use -[UIScreen bounds]
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIScreen.h:76:38: Property 'applicationFrame' is declared deprecated here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIScreen.h:76:38: 'applicationFrame' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
/Users/brianthanhnguyen/dev/MyApp/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/MyApp/Plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/CDVStatusBar.m:369:14: 'setStatusBarHidden:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use -[UIViewController prefersStatusBarHidden]
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:444:63: Property 'statusBarHidden' is declared deprecated here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:444:63: 'setStatusBarHidden:' has been explicitly marked dep
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a thread on the [Meteor Forum](https://forums.meteor.com/t/ios-10-compatibility/26065/17) about this.

In order to get it working, I had to delete `.meteor/cordova-build` and run:

```
meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp@https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp.git#8bf95eed3f313299fc2de33658866278eea2cdc5
```

Keep an eye on this [Git repo](https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp/tree/swift3) for more updates.